# How to calculate the time for a transaction start to commit to be communicated to the client application?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have a 2 node AG in sync mode.

AG transaction delay value is about 60ms/s. This is the sum of all transactions delays in that second.

The transactions/sec value is around 1000.

So the delay per transaction is 1000/60 = 16ms.

The disk read/sec value is in the range of 5 to 25. Disk write/sec is in the range of 15 to 30.

How to calculate the time from the start of transaction, commit and the moment this is communicated to the client application?

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple extended events, capture network packets, and write your own correlation logic.

Otherwise, "good enough" is to use the given performance counter values for overhead as already stated in the original posting.

Comment: Is the transaction delay value the time it takes to commit to the synchronous secondary replica? So just the bit where the tx is sent to the secondary, hardened and ack received at primary?

Comment: "Total delay in waiting for unterminated commit acknowledgment for all the current transactions, in milliseconds."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-database-replica?view=sql-server-ver16